# Socket - receive client request when there are 2 consecutive crlf

Tags: c, sockets

I am implementing the tiny server, and have a trouble to detect the client request. The requirement require that we only accept the client's request if there are two consecutive CRLFs. So my current code is:

```
int bytes_read = recv(client, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0); 
if (bytes_read < 0) {
       printfError("Problem with recv call", false);
}


if(checkRequest(buffer)) {
   // Accept client's request
}
```

In my checkRequest, I will check the client's request method, filename, and HTTP:

```
bool checkRequest(char *buff, int &valid, int &ext) {
    char *request_method = strtok(buff, " ");
    char *request_filename = strtok(NULL, " ");
    char *request_http = strtok(NULL, " ");


    int i;
    bool isValid = false;
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        if(*request_http == '\r') {
            isValid = true;
            *request_http++;
            if(*request_http == '\n') {
                // Keep checking
                *request_http++;
            } else {
                isValid = false;
            }
        } 
        if(!isValid) break; // Not 2 consecutive CRLFs;
    }

    return isValid;
```

The problem that I have when testing on telnet is when I hit the first enter; it is only able to detect the first crlf. I also try to but the recv() between the while loop but it will stuck inside it.

Answer (score 1):

Although there are more thorough and robust ways to achieve this, this is the simple solution to your problem.  There is never any guarantee how many bytes you will receive from the senders call so you must keep calling recv until you've got the quantity of data you expect.

```
const unsigned int kuiBytesExpected = 4;
unsigned int uiBytesReceived = 0;
while ( uiBytesReceived < kuiBytesExpected )
{
  int bytes_read = recv(client, buffer + uiBytesReceived, kuiBytesExpected - uiBytesReceived, 0); 

  // recv returns 0 if client disonnects and -1 on error
  if ( bytes_read < 1 ) 
  {
       printfError("Problem with recv call", false);
       break;
  }
  else
  {
    uiBytesReceived += bytes_read;
  }
}

if ( uiBytesReceived == kuiBytesExpected  )
{
  if(checkRequest(buffer)) 
  {
     // Accept client's request
  }    
}
```